# "Ilist", "IEnumerable" no contiene una definición para "Skip"

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

Recientemente me he visto en la necesidad de buscar los números faltantes en una secuencia numérica. Investigando esto lo he resuelto de la siguiente manera:

```
 List<int> myLista = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 9 };
 int primero = myLista.OrderBy(x => x).First();
 int ultimo = myLista.OrderBy(x => x).Last();
 var resultado = Enumerable.Range(primero, ultimo - primero + 1).Except(list);
```

Pero ahora me surge también la necesidad de saber ***exactamente dónde se interrumpe la secuencia de números?***, estuve investigando y encontré la siguiente página que tratan este tema: [Find Missing Values in a Sequence of Numbers and Other Sequence Related lists as IEnumerable Extensions](http://omegacoder.com/?p=1032) Aquí hay un método que hace justamente eso que quiero, se llamada:`SequenceReportMissingsBreakStarts`.

Pero todos los métodos están creando "consultas" con efectos secundarios significativos, es por esto que decidí tomar el ejemplo que se muestra en los comentarios sugeridos por otro usuario. Pero no logro hacer que esto me funcione:

```
private IEnumerable SequenceFindMissings(IEnumerable sequence)
{
    return sequence.Zip(sequence.Skip(1), (a, b) => Enumerable.Range(a + 1, (b - a) - 1))
                       .SelectMany(s => s);
}

private bool IsSequenceBroken(IEnumerable sequence)
{
    return sequence.Zip(sequence.Skip(1), (a, b) => b - a)
                       .Any(v => v != 1);
}

private IEnumerable SequenceReportMissingsBreakStarts(IList sequence)
{
    return sequence.Zip(sequence.Skip(1), (a, b) => new { b, a })
                       .Where(v => v.b - v.a > 1)
                       .Select(v => v.a);
}
```

Recibo el error: `Ilist`, `IEnumerable` no contiene una definición para `Skip` y tengo agregado las referencias:

> `using System.Linq;`
>
> `using System.Collections;`
>
> `using System.Collections.Generic;`

**Por qué no puedo usar "Skip" en estos métodos, cómo debo modificarlos para que funcione?** , o alguna sugerencia sin tener que usar consultas?

**Entorno:** Visual Studio 2017 & .NetFramework 4.5.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En principio debes tener en cuenta que estás pasando parámetros a tus métodos mediante **Interfaces** (`IEnumerable`, `IList`).

El problema está en que debes indicar el tipo de objeto que contendrán estas "Listas genéricas" para poder posteriormente utilizar **LinQ** (`Skip()`).

En tu caso serían "listas genéricas" del tipo **`int`** (`IEnumerable<int>`), el código sería así:

```
    private IEnumerable<int> SequenceFindMissings(IEnumerable<int> sequence)
    {
        return sequence.Zip(sequence.Skip(1), (a, b) => Enumerable.Range(a + 1, (b - a) - 1))
                           .SelectMany(s => s);
    }

    private bool IsSequenceBroken(IEnumerable<int> sequence)
    {
        return sequence.Zip(sequence.Skip(1), (a, b) => b - a)
                           .Any(v => v != 1);
    }

    private IEnumerable<int> SequenceReportMissingsBreakStarts(IList<int> sequence)
    {
        return sequence.Zip(sequence.Skip(1), (a, b) => new { b, a })
                           .Where(v => v.b - v.a > 1)
                           .Select(v => v.a);
    }
```

Comment: Wow, no me fijé en algo tan sencillo como esto: `<int>`, muchas gracias Rafael.

Comment: @J.Rodríguez: Incluso, si no vas a realizar algún tipo de inyección de dependencias o polimorfismo, puedes directamente pasar un `List<int>`.

Comment: Esto ha sido muy útil, gracias.